# Handling CGFloat with an NSScanner on arm64

Tags: cocoa-touch, double, nsscanner, arm64, cgfloat

Apparently `CGFloat` is `double` on arm64:

```
#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE double
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
# define CGFLOAT_MIN DBL_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX DBL_MAX
#else
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 0
# define CGFLOAT_MIN FLT_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX FLT_MAX
#endif
```

So the code

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
CGFloat c[components];
[scanner scanFloat:&c[i]]
```

which was working fine for 32-bit apps, is broken for 64-bit. It can be replaced with

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
CGFloat c[components];
#if CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 
   [scanner scanDouble:&c[i]]; 
#else 
   [scanner scanFloat:&c[i]]; 
#endif
```

But is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSScanner` only supports [a few basic types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html), so you're going to need to have that #if directive somewhere. That said, if you're using this often you could subclass NSScanner or use a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) to make the code more elegant.

I think the category-based code would look something like:

NSScanner+MyAdditions.h:

```
#import "NSScanner.h"

@interface NSScanner (MyAdditions)
  - (BOOL)my_scanCGFloat:(CGFloat *) cgFloatValue
@end
```

NSScanner+MyAdditions.m:

```
#import "NSScanner+MyAdditions.h"

@implementation NSScanner (MyAdditions)
  - (BOOL)my_scanCGFloat:(CGFloat *) cgFloatValue {
#if CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 
    return [self scanDouble:cgFloatValue]; 
#else 
    return [self scanFloat:cgFloatValue]; 
#endif
}
@end
```