# 32 bit vs 64 bit. sqrt() and sqrtf() issues

Tags: swift, 32bit-64bit, xcode6

I've been having issues with math functions on swift. Sinf(), sqrtf() work on the iPhone 5 simulator but do not work on the iPhone 5S. Sin() and sqrt() work on iPhone 5S simulator but not on the iPhone 5. All my variables were introduced as CGFLoat(). I figured it has something to do with the 32 bit vs 64 bit but I could not find a fix for this. Is there a way to make sine and square root functions to work on both iphone5 and iPhone 5s? I am running Xcode6-Beta2.
Thanks

Comment: What line code of works on the simulator but not the device? And what error do you get?

Comment: Just update to Beta 5, then you can use the math functions with CGFloat without problems.

Comment: I downloaded and installed Xcode 6 Beta 5 today. This version doesn't work very well for me. When I open the file it says indexing, and then nothing happens. If I try to compile it, the status says 'building' but nothing is happening. Anybody has an idea of whats going on?

Comment: Added Foundation framework and everything is back to normal. Martin R thanks for the tip. Upgrading to Beta 5 fixed everything!

Answer (score 1):

`CGFloat` [is a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847896/handling-cgfloat-with-an-nsscanner-on-arm64) at 64-bit environment, use `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE` to verify whether it is float or double.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to Beta5 fixed the issue.